# Warning rmdir (/web/uploads/media/default/0001/01)

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I installed Symfony 2.8.13, Sonata Admin Bundle 3.9 and Sonata Media Bundle 3.3.
I have an entity Color and a column media as a foreign key of Sonata Media.
I can insert and delete a media, but I can't modify it. When I modify the image, It shows a error message:

```
Warning: rmdir(/projet/myproject/web/uploads/media/default/0001/01): Directory not empty
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I added `'by_reference' => false` :

```
$fileFieldOptions = array(
    'required' => false,
    'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
    'context' => 'default',
    'by_reference' => false
 );
```